How to go directly to the town in Hay Day
In the mobile game Hay Day, I cannot find how to go to the Town from the main farm.
When there is a quest related to the town, then there is a link to the farm, but sometimes I want to go to the farm just to check in.

Do you want to go to the town or farm? It’s unclear, because you say you want to go to both at different points in the question.

You have to repair the train station, at which point you can travel to the town whenever you want.
According to the Fandom,

Repairing the farm's train station costs 39,000 coins, takes three days (or 97 diamonds) and awards 39 experience points. After taking the handcar to go to the town players must repair the town's train station and the Town Hall. It is free to repair these.

It later says to return to the farm, you have to take the handcar back.
